Why doesn't the compiler optimize strlen() calls in a loop, despite it being a pure function? And how would [[reproducible]] affect this?
I have two functions that convert a string to lowercase. The first one calls strlen() in every iteration, while the second one only calls it after modifying the string. I expected the compiler to optimize the first function to behave like the second, given that strlen() is a pure function. However, the generated assembly code differs. Here are the functions:
void lower_quadratic(char *s) {
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
      s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
}

void lower_still_quadratic(char *s) {
  size_t i, n = strlen(s);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z') {
      s[i] += 'a' - 'A';
      n = strlen(s);
    }
}

You can see the compiled output for these functions on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/feE7sc9Gs
Why doesn't the compiler optimize the first function to behave like the second?
Would using the [[reproducible]] attribute (or similar) on strlen() help the compiler make this optimization?
If [[reproducible]] were used, should we expect the compiler to ignore the general optimization principle of "move invariant calls out of loops"? In other words, should we rely solely on the attribute and expect the compiler to optimize based on that, rather than applying general optimization strategies?
Are there any compiler flags or techniques that could encourage this optimization?
I'm using GCC 14.1 on x86_64 with -O3 optimization level, as seen in the Godbolt link. The assembly output clearly shows that strlen is called in each iteration in the first function, but not in the second.
Any insights into the compiler's behavior, the impact of [[reproducible]], and potential ways to achieve this optimization would be greatly appreciated.

It is because strlen() is a function that the first cannot be optimized (not without the compiler doing some very aggressive analysis), since the loop condition relies on the result of a function that, as far as the compiler knows, may change at any time.

The compiler doesn't understand that you are only changing the case of the string, so s[i] += 'a' - 'A'; just might introduce a new null-character that changes the length of the string. strlen is pure only if the parameter doesn't change.

@BoP Thanks, but I'm comparing the first two functions, not modified vs unmodified strings. Both modify the string identically. My question is why the compiler doesn't optimize lower_quadratic to match lower_still_quadratic, since strlen(s) could safely be moved out of the loop when the string is not modified.

@Dúthomhas But aren't library functions like strlen() well-known to the compiler? Compilers often have built-in knowledge or even implementations of these functions. Shouldn't this allow for optimization?

@AndyLee Those optimizations only apply to certain edge cases like a constexpr string literal and alike, where the compiler can replace the parametric library call by a constant or fixed instruction sequence. It does not mean the compiler will be able to optimize invocations with arbitrary dynamic inputs.

You're changing the content of s within the loop.  The compiler you're using isn't able to do enough flow analysis to determine that you never write a null character to it (and I'd be surprised to find one that would).  So it needs to compute the length each time round, even if it is able to hoist that computation when s[i] isn't written in the loop.
BTW, this is a non-portable function - there are character encodings where it will catch more characters than you intend.
Of course, the more idiomatic function never measures the length of the string, but just stops when it reaches '\0':
for (;  *s;  ++s) {
    *s = tolower((unsigned char)*s); /* or locale-unaware alternative */
}


strlen() can be [[unsequenced]], (which obviously means it's [[reproducible]]).  But that doesn't allow calls to be combined when there's an intervening write operation, so does not help with this code which modifies the content of the string between calls.
It only allows the compiler to make the same assumptions about the function from its declaration as it can with the definition visible.

How can it catch more characters than intended?

As just one example: In an EBCDIC (code-page 1146) environment, the non-letter character } (xD0) is greater than A (xC1) and less than Z (xE9).

Wouldn't you have to convert any EBCDIC data to something ASCII compatible anyways before doing anything with it in C?

No - why would you think that?  C doesn't mandate any particular character coding.

Maybe it's just me, but I wouldn't touch data in a codepage where the alphabet has holes.

As author, you don't get to choose what environments your users have, so it's a good idea not to fail unexpectedly when their requirements differ from your preferences!

Thanks, but I'm still confused. Couldn't the compiler use flow analysis to determine that strlen() only needs to be called after modifying the string in an if block, and otherwise does nothing at all, rather than calling it on every iteration? This seems like a straightforward optimization. Why is this challenging for the compiler?

@Andy - The pattern probably doesn't occur often enough for this compiler's authors to spend the development effort (and precious run time) optimising it.  But if it's something you can't live without, why not contribute a change to implement that?
